# Program stops when starting another executable using system()

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a loop which checks to see if a certain process is active. If the process isn't active, the main program launches it using the `system()` call. Example:

```
#define MODERATING_INTERVAL 1000
...
while (true) {
    if (!isProcessRunning())
        system("helper.exe");
    Sleep(MODERATING_INTERVAL);
}
```

My problem is that everything runs fine, but the main program is paused as long as the `helper.exe`program is running, so the loop will not iterate.

I couldn't find a solution myself, so I'm asking: is it possible to make the example loop continue iterating while the invoked program is running?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `system("start helper.exe");`

Comment: use `CreateProcess` for start `helper.exe`

Comment: Thanks, that works. What difference is there between using `start` to call executables and not using any prefix?

Comment: > help start
Starts a separate window to run a specified program or command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the normal behaviour of `system`. If you want to start a new process that runs concurrently with your current program you need to use [`CreateProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa).

Comment: or fork/exec to be posix-compatible,

Comment: @RichardHodges Windows isn't a POSIX system, and does not support fork.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_POSIX_subsystem

Comment: @richard Yes, that's long since dead. Perhaps if you want to peruse this dead end you might like to show code that calls fork on modern day Windows? By modern day I mean anything later than win2k.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I think even Microsoft have finally realised that the future is Linux: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux - this is very much alive.

Comment: @richard How do you call fork and exec then in Windows today? Your posting suggests you don't have Windows experience.